# PySpark mllib Logistic Regression error "List object has no attribute first"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to do a straightforward training of a logistic regression model.  My training data, model and error message are shown below.  Why do I get this 'list' object has no attribute 'first' error?

```
train_data = numdata.collect()
train_data[:3]

[LabeledPoint(1.0, [2.0,36.0,0.0,100.0,100.0,38.0,0.0,100.0,95.0,100.0,100.0]), 
LabeledPoint(1.0, [0.0,77.0,16.0,100.0,99.0,86.0,1.0,99.0,100.0,99.0,95.0]),
LabeledPoint(1.0, [0.0,22.0,0.0,100.0,95.0,21.0,1.0,95.0,100.0,100.0,100.0])]

lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(train_data)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(train_data)
>
> C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\classification.pyc
>   in train(cls, data, iterations, step, miniBatchFraction,
>   initialWeights, regParam, regType, intercept, validateData,
>   convergenceTol)
>       319                                  bool(intercept), bool(validateData), float(convergenceTol))
>       320 
>   --> 321         return _regression_train_wrapper(train, LogisticRegressionModel, data, initialWeights)
>       322 
>       323
>
> C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\regression.pyc in
>   _regression_train_wrapper(train_func, modelClass, data, initial_weights)
>       206 def _regression_train_wrapper(train_func, modelClass, data, initial_weights):
>       207     from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionModel
>   --> 208     first = data.first()
>       209     if not isinstance(first, LabeledPoint):
>       210         raise TypeError("data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint, but got %s" % type(first))
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'first'

Answer (score 4):

> raise TypeError("data should be an RDD of LabeledPoint

You have a Python `list` because that is what `collect()` returns. You need an `RDD`, so

```
lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(numdata)
```

Or, I assumed you've split `numdata` like so for a 70/30% split

```
(trainingData, testData) = numdata.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
```

so use that `trainingData` RDD

Answer (score 2):

You should be presenting the `train` method with an RDD, not a list. That's what the error message says.

By doing `.collect()`, you've gathered the data in the RDD into memory, and you're overwriting the `train_data` variable. So now, it's no longer an RDD but an in-memory Python list.

Instead, you could train on `num_data` directly. Or, if you want to train on 3 rows, as in your example:

```
train_data = num_data.take(3)
lrm = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(train_data)
```